# Javascritp app.js function returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs

I'm trying to write a simple function retrieving the contract address with a simple call. Anyway while the address value is correct in the function scope, the return value calling the function in that way is giving me an undefined error.

```
//Here the call

console.log("Indirizo con chiamata",App.getContractAddress());


//Here the function code


getContractAddress: function() {

RevenueShare.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  myContractInstance=RevenueShare.deployed();

myContractInstance.then(function(instance){
    return instance.address;
}).then(function(address){
  console.log("Indirizzo in funzione:",address);
  return address;
});
},
```

Any Help???

Comment: You are using truffle i think, but you are not catching any errors form the `RevenueShare.deployed()` call. if `instance.address` is undefined then there is a problem in the contract deployment. try to log `instance.address` and see what it gives.

Comment: Yes I Am using truffle. Well actually instance.address is working, the console log inside the function gives out the right result (The contract address). Meanwhile when I try to call the function (as example in the first console.log) it returns an undefined.

Comment: I it is just a javascript problem. promise returns are asyncronous so if you call your function, the result would be returned late and thus not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a javascript problem. try this fix :

**Function**

```
getContractAddress: function() {
 return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
RevenueShare.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  myContractInstance=RevenueShare.deployed();

myContractInstance.then(function(instance){
    return instance.address;
}).then(function(address){
  console.log("Indirizzo in funzione:",address);
  res(address);
});

})

}
```

**Function Call**

```
App.getContractAddress()
.then(
    data=>{
        console.log("Indirizo con chiamata",data);
    })
```